Google Local Service Ads API problem getting a report
I need to gather a report from Google Local Services Ads API. Found documentation, trying using accountReports:search method to get a report. I set up all necessary Google Cloud Console credentials and OAuth2.0, it works fine. The problem is that it's just returning me a blank object with 200 status. Also inserted all necessary headers from a documentation page.
enter image description here
I've tried inserting end and start date optional fields but got the same result - blank object.
